# "Can't find mapping" error in Rails (when using Devise Gem)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I am using Devise to authenticate users. I am trying to make a form/update method to update the password. The form generates correctly and it picks up the route as well. However, I am receiving the following error:

"Could not find devise mapping for path "/users/updatepw". This may happen for two reasons: 1) You forgot to wrap your route inside the scope block. For example: devise_scope :user do get "/some/route" => "some_devise_controller" end 2) You are testing a Devise controller bypassing the router. If so, you can explicitly tell Devise which mapping to use: @request.env["devise.mapping"] = Devise.mappings[:user]"

The first option doesn't seem to be the cause, this is my routes.rb:

```
devise_scope :users do
  ...
  post "/users/updatepw", to: "users/registrations#update_password", as :update_pw
  ...  
end
...
resources :users #I don't know if this is needed considering the devise block, but commenting it out doesn't fix the problem..
```

So it *is* wrapped.

As for the second option...I don't really understand it...I am not trying to test anything...?

My question is really 2-fold: 
1) What does the error mean, considering I'm not trying to run any tests?
2) Where do I put the corrective line ("@request.env["devise.mapping"] = Devise.mappings[:user]") to fix the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing the `as: resource_name` option in your form. See Devise's password edit

`<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, ...`

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/app/views/devise/passwords/edit.html.erb#L3

Question: Why are you creating your own update password? Devise already provides this.